# Convert vertical text into horizontal in shell

Tags: shell, text, file-manipulation

I just pondered upon this problem while executing some tasks in shell.

How can I convert a `.txt` file which contains text in the following format[vertical direction]:

```
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
```

> ***Note:*** The line without any letter contains a space and EOL

I need to convert to:

```
Hello World
```

I tried the following command: `cat file1.txt |tr '\n' ' ' >file2.txt`

Output:

```
H e l l o  W o r l d
```

How can I proceed further? Sorry, if this question has already appeared. If so, please provide me the link to the solution or any command for the work around.

Comment: First, replace `\n\n` with `' '`, then, replace `\n` with `''` .

Comment: @fedorqui The line without any letter is a space and EOL.. Ill edit the question too..thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are replacing the new lines with spaces. Instead, remove them with `-d`:

```
$ echo "H
> e
>                   # <- there is a space here
> W
> o" | tr -d '\n'
He Wo
```

With a file:

```
tr -d '\n' < file   # there is no need to `cat`!
```

Problem here is that the last new line is removed, so the result is  POSIXly a 0-lines file.

Comment: thanks for your reply :)  How to do for more than one string? .. Like, in the answer you have used `Hello` but what about for the example that I have mention above?..

Comment: @LijuThomas oh, I just put some characters to prevent this being too long. Updated with an example with a space.

Answer (score 2):

You were quite close... :-)
`tr` command has option `-d` to *remove* charactar classes, instead of just replacing.
So:

```
cat file1.txt | tr -d '\n' > file2.txt
```

Will just do...

**UPDATE**: after OP comment, this is a version which preserves empty newlines:

```
cat file1.txt | perl -p -i -e 's/\n(.+)/$1/' > file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :).. I tried the command but the output which I got is `HelloWorld`. My desired output is `Hello World` Can this be achieved?

Comment: @LijuThomas: you're right, sorry... I did not think about empty lines... In an update to my answer I address this case, too... .-)

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
echo "$x"
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
```

Solution:

```
  echo "$x"  |sed 's/^$/bla/'|awk 'BEGIN{OFS="";ORS=" ";RS="bla"}{$1=$1}1'
  Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through all the suggestions and little bit of research, I found a solution for this, wrote a script for the same:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Converting text to horizontal direction

IFS=''
while read line
do
   echo -n $line
done < $1 > $2           # $1 --> file1.txt contain vertical text as mentioned in the question
echo "$(cat $2)"
```

Command:

```
$./convert.sh file1.txt file2.txt
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```